# how could I produce triangular mesh for membrane

Tags: mesh-generation

It is necessary for me to produce triangular mesh on a sphere membrane.

I use  MATLAB pdetool or delaunay for produce mesh. 
How could I do this?

Comment: Did you try a google search? This is the first result I got: http://persson.berkeley.edu/distmesh/. Or maybe try this: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/37004-uniform-sampling-of-a-sphere/content/Uniform%20Sampling%20of%20S2/TriQuad.m

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My favorite free mesh generator is "gmsh". It allows you to create geometry through a variety of means and can produce high-quality 2D and 3D meshes. Gmsh will actually triangulate the spherical shell, which will produce better results than simply triangulating a circle and projecting it up to a hemisphere.

Here's the site where you can find more info and tutorials. http://geuz.org/gmsh/